# How to query items that are in stock in a certain date range?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the following schema for receiving transaction.

```
const receivingTransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    source: {
      type: String,
    },
    receivedItems: [
      {
        itemType: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item_Type" },
        items: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Item",
          },
        ],
        quantity: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
        },
        unitCost: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
        },
        subinventory: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Subinventory",
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

And the following for transferring transaction that will transfer items to a given department from stock

```
const transferTransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    requestingTransaction: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Requesting_Transaction",
      required: true,
    },

    department: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: "Department",
      required: true,
    },

    transferredItems: {
      itemType: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Item_Type",
        required: true,
      },
      items: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Item",
        },
      ],
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Now what I want to query is items that were in stock from x date to y date range.

Here is a sample data for receiving transaction:

```
"transaction": {
        "_id": "62557b6445d54c7c7118be02",
        "source": "World Bank",
        "receivedItems": [
            {
                "itemType": "624dde980335882bf2d0df2c",
                "items": [
                    "62557b5e45d54c7c7118bde2",
                    "62557b5f45d54c7c7118bde4",
                    "62557b6045d54c7c7118bde6",
                    "62557b6045d54c7c7118bde8",
                    "62557b6145d54c7c7118bdea",
                    "62557b6145d54c7c7118bdec",
                    "62557b6145d54c7c7118bdee",
                    "62557b6145d54c7c7118bdf0",
                    "62557b6245d54c7c7118bdf2",
                    "62557b6245d54c7c7118bdf4"
                ],
                "quantity": 10,
                "unitCost": 100,
                "subinventory": "6252bbf785093e0c778f0621",
                "_id": "62557b6445d54c7c7118be03"
            },
            {
                "itemType": "6252c670f5992c9b958f2ce5",
                "items": [
                    "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdf8",
                    "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdfa",
                    "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdfc",
                    "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdfe",
                    "62557b6445d54c7c7118be00"
                ],
                "quantity": 5,
                "unitCost": 600,
                "subinventory": "6252bbf785093e0c778f0621",
                "_id": "62557b6445d54c7c7118be04"
            }
        ],
        "receiptNumber": "68821212-619765376773",
        "user": "6252eab687ec4852535ca063",
        "type": "Receiving_Transaction",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-12T13:15:16.309Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-12T13:15:16.309Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

And for transferring transaction:

```
  "transaction": {
        "transferredItems": {
            "itemType": "6252c670f5992c9b958f2ce5",
            "items": [
                "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdf8",
                "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdfa",
                "62557b6345d54c7c7118bdfc"
            ],
            "quantity": 3
        },
        "_id": "62557ceb45d54c7c7118be30",
        "requestingTransaction": "62557c3c45d54c7c7118be1a",
        "department": "624c33a58a6223667774a9f8",
        "receiptNumber": "239736984389763428736",
        "user": "6252eab687ec4852535ca063",
        "type": "Transferring_Transaction",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-12T13:21:47.004Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-12T13:21:47.004Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: If there is only `receivedItems` and `transferredItems`, won't you have to "replay" all transactions to determine the stock at any particular time?  

Comment: What does "items that are in stock in a certain date range" mean?  E.g., does it mean, between two dates is the stock quantity ever greater than zero?

Comment: @rickhg12hs basically the transaction collection will be used as a history of actions that took place. Rather than replay the transaction, I was thinking of using the createdAt date to somehow identify at what point in time the item was still in stock.

Comment: @rickhg12hs For your second question, say for example there were 10 laptops in stock (recorded in receivingTransaction). Then a certain department asks for 5 laptops, so 5 of them will be transferred (recorded in transferringTransaction). Now at some later date I'd like to use the date as a query and look at that point in time what was in stock(startDate - endDate).

Comment: So, you want to know the available stock at a specific instant then, yes?  I.e., at a specific date, sum(all received) - sum(all transferred), yes?

Comment: From a specific start date to a specific end date, what items were in stock(meaning received but not transferred in that time range)

Comment: So any stock that existed before the start date is to be ignored?  And any stock that existed before the start date, but transferred between the start and end date is also to be ignored?  TBH, I think I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, it's basically a query of what was in stock say from start of March till the end of March. I think its a common usecase just don't know how to write the query